# Managing Vuex state using with NuxtJs on 'universal' mode

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I get used to using `localStorage` with Vuex but as you know on SSR we can not use `localeStorage`. So I searched a solution to keep Vuex `state` on page refresh and run into `vuex-persistedstate` using with `js-cookie` many times.
My question is that do I need really `vuex-persistedstate`? I mean that can I just use `js-cookie` just like the following:

```
import Cookie from 'js-cookie'

const state = {
  firstName: Cookie.get('firstName)
}

const mutations = {
  setFirstName(state, name) {
    state.firstName = name;
    Cookie.set('firstName', name)
}
```

etc.

Comment: I use cookies in nuxt and I've never used vuex-persistedstate. Never even heard of it. I use 'js-cookie' to set cookies and 'cookie' to get them. Just the way I learnt it.

Comment: @Andrew1325 So I can use like the my example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment question. Your example in the question is ok at least for setting the cookie. I set mine in an action first and then commit the mutation to set the state only. As for getting your cookies, you might need a bit more than just setting the state. As I said i use 'cookie' ([see here](https://github.com/jshttp/cookie)) for getting my cookies and I get them through nuxtServerInit, like this:

```
nuxtServerInit({dispatch}, context) {
              return Promise.all([
                dispatch('get_cookies', context),
                //other actions
              ]);
            },
```

and the action itself as follows:

```
get_cookies (vuexContext, context) {
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const cookieConst = cookie.parse(context.req.headers.cookie || '')
                if (cookieConst.hasOwnProperty('YourCookieName')) {
                    //commit mutations here
                }
                else {
                    resolve(false)
                }
              })
            },
```

Obviously you need to import:

```
import cookies from 'js-cookie'
import cookie from 'cookie'
```

You can put a fair bit of stuff into cookies, I set user details and shopping cart. I also store an access token in my cookies and validate it in my backend so I can persist an auth state.